# Export SQL query with INTO, to CSV from DBEAVER

Tags: sql, csv, export, dbeaver

I have problem exporting data with DBeaver and temporary tables.

When trying to export data to csv, with right button, from a query like this:

`select count (*) from ## temporarytable`

##temporarytable had already been created and executed successfully, just like the previous query, but its export to CSV fails

I only get this result:

`Task execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [2706] [42W33]: SQL Anywhere Error -141: Table '## temporarytable' not found`

Could it be a DBeaver configuration problem?

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using? Is it possible you need to specify the DB?

Comment: Hi. The SQL engine is Sybase